# Show the overlay closest to the clicked button Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, frontend, overlay, web-frontend

I have multiple cards on a page each with the buttons and overlays having the same class. When I click the ellipsis, the overlay related that ellipse should be shown. I've tried to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method however it hasn't worked

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
        <img src="../images/icons/white-logo-icon-only.svg" alt="" class="me-2" />
        <p>Video Subject</p>
      </div>
      <a class="show-overlay"><img src="../images/icons/ellipsis.svg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="../images/icons/play-btn.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-overlay text-center">
      <p>Share via me</p>
      <div class="d-flex share-btn">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/fb-bg-2.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/whatsapp.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/twit.svg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
        <img src="../images/icons/white-logo-icon-only.svg" alt="" class="me-2" />
        <p>Video Subject</p>
      </div>
      <a class="show-overlay"><img src="../images/icons/ellipsis.svg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="../images/icons/play-btn.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-overlay text-center">
      <p>Share via</p>
      <div class="d-flex share-btn">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/fb-bg-2.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/whatsapp.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/twit.svg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

show the overlay when the user clicks the ellipsis

```
   $(".card-overlay").hide();
        $(".show-overlay").click(function () {
    
            $(this).closest(".card-overlay").show();
    
            // $(".card-overlay").show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` is used to look for a ***parent*** element. `.card-overlay` is a child of a sibling to a parent of the clicked `.show-overlay`.

To fix the problem use `closest()` to find a common ancestor of *both* the clicked element and the target, in this case `.card`, then use `find()` to retrieve the target from within that ancestor. Try this:

```js
$(".show-overlay").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').find('.card-overlay').show();
});
```

```css
.card-overlay { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
        <img src="../images/icons/white-logo-icon-only.svg" alt="" class="me-2" />
        <p>Video Subject</p>
      </div>
      <a class="show-overlay"><img src="../images/icons/ellipsis.svg" alt="" />...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="../images/icons/play-btn.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-overlay text-center">
      <p>Share via me</p>
      <div class="d-flex share-btn">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/fb-bg-2.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/whatsapp.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/twit.svg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
        <img src="../images/icons/white-logo-icon-only.svg" alt="" class="me-2" />
        <p>Video Subject</p>
      </div>
      <a class="show-overlay"><img src="../images/icons/ellipsis.svg" alt="" />...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src="../images/icons/play-btn.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-overlay text-center">
      <p>Share via</p>
      <div class="d-flex share-btn">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/fb-bg-2.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/whatsapp.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/icons/twit.svg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I moved the hiding of `.card-overlay` to CSS instead of JS. This is to avoid the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) caused due to JS being executed after the page loads.